# jQuery: change css color based on inline style width

Tags: jquery

If I have this html, how would I change the color based on the width?

```
    <div id="progress_bar" class="meter-bg">
        <div class="meter" style="width: 67%;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

For example, if the width is between 0 and 33%, green. If it's 33%-66% orange. If it's 66%-100% red.

Comment: This is all very good.  May I ask...what should I do if the contain in which this is in is loaded via ajax?  Sorry!

Comment: Added an example when loading the content from AJAX and need to setup the progress bar once the content is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my solution: http://jsfiddle.net/jKWFz/

```
var oMeter = $('.meter');
var percent = 100 * (oMeter.width() / $('#progress_bar').width());

if (percent < 33)
{
     oMeter.css('background-color', 'green');
}
else if (percent > 33 && percent <= 66)
{
     oMeter.css('background-color', 'orange');    
}
else
{
     oMeter.css('background-color', 'red');
}
```

Edit: If the content is loaded in AJAX, all you need to do is wrap the above code in a function, and call it when the content been loaded.

For example:

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jKWFz/2/

```
function setupMeter() {
    var oMeter = $('.meter');
    var percent = 100 * (oMeter.width() / oMeter.closest('.meter-bg').width());

    if (percent < 33) {
        oMeter.css('background-color', 'green');
    }
    else if (percent > 33 && percent <= 66) {
        oMeter.css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
    else {
        oMeter.css('background-color', 'red');
    }
}

// Example when loading from AJAX:
$.get("some_content.html", function(data) {
    $('#container').html(data);
    setupMeter();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

another way to do it that would allow you to have multiple class for numbers:

```
var p = 74; // your percentage from someplace
var colors = ['one','two','three']; // names of your css classes
var chosen = colors[0];
i = 1;
while(i < colors.length) { 
    var m = Math.round((i/colors.length) * 100); 
    if(p > m){   
        chosen = colors[i];
        i++;       
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
console.log(chosen) // chosen now contains the array var you want depending on % p
```