# jQuery CSS not applying

Tags: jquery

I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619025/jquery-change-css-color-based-on-inline-style-width) jQuery with this:

```
//Table select
$("#reports-table tr").click(
    function(e) {
        if($(e.target).is(".row-button-small")) return;

        var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $('#details').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id);
        setupMeter();
        $('#reports-table').width(640);
});
```

The problem is, the jQuery css shows for half a second (right after load of the details div), and then reverts to the stylesheet css...
**That is, the CSS from the link! Sorry to be unclear!**
Why!?

**Here is the "setupMeter" function:**

```
function setupMeter() {
   var oMeter = $('.meter');
   var percent = 100 * (oMeter.width() / oMeter.closest('.meter-bg').width());

   if (percent < 33) {
       oMeter.css('background-color', 'green');
   }
   else if (percent > 33 && percent <= 66) {
       oMeter.css('background-color', 'orange');
   }
   else {
       oMeter.css('background-color', 'red');
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the stylesheet css"?

Comment: what is `setupMeter();` doing? My guess would be that you are reloading the table with ajax or something similar.

Comment: I mean my attached css...sorry. :)

Comment: I added the "setupMeter" function from the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  I needed to run the post-processing after the callback...

```
        $('#details').load('/members/details/'+detail_id,function(){
            $(this).show();
            $('.meter').setupMeter();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely that your page is reloading because you're clicking on a link. Place `return false` or [`e.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) at the end of the `click` handler.

```
$("#reports-table tr").click(
    function(e) {
         // prevent the default behavior of a link
        e.preventDefault();

        if($(e.target).is(".row-button-small")) return;

        var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $('#details').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id);
        setupMeter();
        $('#reports-table').width(640);

         // prevent the default behavior of a link
        return false;
});
```

This would explain why it shows the updated style for only a second or so.

---

**EDIT:** If the elements being styled are inside the `#details` element, they (and their new styles) will be overwritten by the `.load()` content. If that's the case, you should your `setupMeter` as a callback.

```
    $('#details').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id, setupMeter);
```

Comment: @Kevin: From all appearances, *something* is causing your page to reload. This is what you need to prevent. Try placing the `e.preventDefault()` at the top. I see you have a `return` statement up there. I'll update. Otherwise you'll need to provide more info.

Comment: I am confused...If I make this as simple as loading the page, and then setting css with a return false at the end, I still get this problem.  Could it be extraneous?

Comment: @Kevin: *"If I make this as simple as loading the page..."* If you're saying that part of the script is to load the same page, then your `.css()` updates will be lost. Or if the elements you're styling are inside the `#details` section, they'll be overwritten. If that's what you mean, then the styling should be done in a callback to `load()`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this. I don't know if it will help, but try adding `!important` to the CSS file rules.

James

Answer (score 0):

Your global stylesheet might be overriding your inline stylesheet setting.

Try this:

```
$("#reports-table').css("width", "640px !important");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//Table select
$("#reports-table tr").click( function(e) {

        if($(e.target).is(".row-button-small")) return;

        ev.stopPropagation();

        var detail_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $(this).addClass("selected");
        $(this).siblings().removeClass("selected");
        $('#details').show().load('/members/details/'+detail_id, function() {
          setupMeter();
          $('#reports-table').width(640);
        });

        return false;
});
```